# Set type of static property to an array of the instance type

Tags: typescript, this, typescript-class

I have a class `Foo` that has a static `instances` property holding references to all created instances. Then, I have a class `Bar` extending `Foo`:

```
class Foo {
    static instances: Foo[];

    fooProp = "foo";

    constructor() {
        let ctor = this.constructor as typeof Foo;
        ctor.instances.push(this);
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    barProp = "bar";
}
```

However, the type of `Bar.instances` is `Foo[]`, rather than `Bar[]`, which causes the following error:

```
let foo = new Foo();
let bar = new Bar();

Foo.instances[0].fooProp; // works
Bar.instances[0].barProp; // Property 'barProp' does not exist on type 'Foo'. ts(2339)
```

I tried using `InstanceType<this>` for the type of `instances`, but it still wouldn't work:

```
class Foo {
    static instances: InstanceType<this>[]; // A 'this' type is available only in a non-static member of a class or interface. ts(2526)
    ...
}
```

It looks like my problem is related to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863) in the TypeScript repo regarding a polymorphic "this". Is this true and what I want to do is currently impossible, or I'm missing sometihng?

Playground link [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.4#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PQgFzNglsNPgHY5gnACmEAXHIgNoC6A3KupgGaIAKATvAAO0ALzQA5D3gT2nDMHhls-AK7Bs8fgAoAlCnmYMIKtmgatY6NgAW+CADpFytRf7RI1gJ5Cq8Lgzw7EZGbg6k5JQ0DkKqEDbatva6wZgAvqgZqKCQMABCYO5UAB7YVCQAJjAISGhGAEaFAsJWEo38spkcJmbSViRUAO6Beuw90O39Q9AFOikcNeHKFNQQjAAMzA7SzUKs0AD0B9CDWgDWEKizS5GrG1vtu-tH0LtU-Nheko+CQhLQFXgNGgJHgZhK9jMSm8vkkNQkDmsEG0ACYAMxogCculQQA).

Comment: tl;dr TypeScript does not track mutations. `push` method mutates your original array. See my article: https://catchts.com/mutations

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript has correctly identified the error.
In your case, static instances array will hold instances of Foo and Bar alike.

Consider adding this to your example and examine the logs:

```js
console.log(Foo.instances[0] instanceof Foo); // true
console.log(Foo.instances[0] instanceof Bar); // false, barProp will not exist on this instance

console.log(Foo.instances[1] instanceof Foo); // true
console.log(Foo.instances[1] instanceof Bar); // true, barProp would be 'bar'
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.4#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PQgFzNglsNPgHY5gnACmEAXHIgNoC60AvNCwNyrqYBmiAAoAneAAd20AOSD40nnwzB4ZbCICuwbPBEAKAJQolmDCCrZo23VOwALfBAB0KtZusjokaNgCe4qnh%20BngeU1MPJ1JyShoncQ0IOz17RwMwzABfVGzUUEgYACEwTyoAD2wqEgATGAQkNFMAIxLRCSlpFpEFHN5zSzkpEioAdxDDHn7oLqHR6GL9dN5XCHhzJxB4AHM9eqi1CmoIRgAGVmjcWKCQ9OgAejufTSo81VX1zZ29i8OaU-ODldggtbg9oPwwCAIFQADTTVpiSQjfAgEDQEjwSzlRyWVQ%20BwwH6xZZvNZUDbbXaIfYxI6MACMANpgWC9VBj3UGheKzJFK%201KJdMZxEB1GuIK49w5zzhXTaSPgGhA1WmVBkXWkvAe31FfzOTjk8slYJGugA1hBUA8FjTLnT9XLEcbHvKqCI-OqERJpNBqvAaOjMdBsThoHi-AEZPVpE4fBA9AAmADMSYAnAZUEA)

If you want to store all instances of Foo in one array and all instances of Bar in another, you need to override the `static instances` in the Bar class:

```
class Bar extends Foo {
    static instances: Bar[] = []

    barProp = 'bar';
}
```

```
console.log(Foo.instances.length); // 1
console.log(Foo.instances[0].fooProp); // 'foo'

console.log(Bar.instances.length); // 1
console.log(Bar.instances[0].barProp); // 'bar'
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.4#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PQgFzNglsNPgHY5gnACmEAXHIgNoC60AvNCwNyrqYBmiAAoAneAAd20AOSD40nnwzB4ZbCICuwbPBEAKAJQolmDCCrZo23VOwALfBAB0KtZusjokaNgCe4qnh%20BngeU1MPJ1JyShoncQ0IOz17RwMwzABfVGzUUEgYACEwTyoAD2wqEgATGAQkNFNyAiJo3Fi6aGKRFikWXlMAIxLRCSlpYZEFHN5zSzkpEioAdxDDHjnoScWVrpL13lcIeHMnEHgAcz16qLUKamdzEgv7dOgAenfoAEY81WPTucrjc2vcaIwAAzMJxyUbiN6fGRyaSHf4nKhnS56bq3GIPM5VF52BFfX5HdGYq440EdSHQyZwkkySYooA)

Answer (score 0):

That Bar is extending Foo doesn't mean, that already declared variables change their type. So the static variable 'instance' will always be of type Foo[] because you declared it as that in your Foo class.
I think 'this' will not work, because 'this' refers to an object and in the static context their is no object to which this can point to.